# How to define functions properly and implement them?

Tags: c++

This structure resembles my code, I get an error: prototype for int A::getA() const does not match any in class A. My other problem is the operator<< overloading. I can not get it to work properly and I get an explicit qualification in declaration error. I tried getting the .hpp in a namespace because I saw something similar in another question posted here but this did not help. If you give me a solution me can you also provide me with details as to why my code is breaking?

```
//define.hpp

class A{
...

int getA() const;
int getAa() const;

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A& obj); // defined outside of the class



//implement.cpp

ostream& define::operator<<(ostream& out, const A& obj){
    return out << obj.getA() 
                << obj.getAa()
                << endl;
};

int A::getA() const{ ... };
int A::getAa() const{ ... };

int main(){

    return 0
}
```

Comment: I don't see any access specifiers. both methods are currently private and therefore unaccessible to operator << defined outside of your class.

Comment: You did `#include "define.hpp"`, didn't you?

Comment: This code does not reproduce the error in the question.

Comment: The functions are public, define is the .hpp which I include and I implement the function in it. I did include it I thought it was understandable.

Comment: It's better to strip everything out of both files that doesn't cause the error, and then update your question to include each complete file, it's not even worth trying to guess what might be causing your error based on what you left out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in the global scope, like your `operator<<` function, does not need to be scoped. So skip the `define::` part of the definition:

```
ostream& operator<<(...) { ... }
```

Comment: That fixed the error thanks, how do I know it is in global scope?

Comment: @EcoGiko In the header file you declared in in the global scope. Just because it's in a specific header or source file puts declarations in any specific scope.